# Port load balance with IPTables

Tags: iptables

If my clients connect to my server on port 5000, how would I set IPTables, to split them evenly between 5001 and 5002?

Answer (score 0):

All of this must be done with caution and make sure you have serial/terminal access because there is a chance of you losing your network connection

First enable ipV4 forwarding

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5001
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5002
```